# Can I change the <soap:address location in my java WS app?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, server, port

I deployed a WS in my public ip XXXXXXXXXXX but when I use it WS. the <soap:address location... does not take the public(XXXXXXXXXXX ) ip. it take the intranet ip (YYYYYYYYYYYY) of the server thats is not allow to public.

its my wsdl service:

```
http://appexample:8282/WsToPublicPPL/Rad?wsdl
```

and the <soap:address location...  turs to:

```
<wsdl:service name="Rad">
  <wsdl:port binding="tns:RadSoapBinding" name="RadPort">
    <soap:address location="http://172.19.22.190:8282/WsToPublicPPL/Rad"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

like 172.19.22.190 is and internal IP i can't add the WS client to apps.

how can I solve it?
The WS is made in Java with Maven.

I apreciate your help!